# Is there a way to link a Label in LaunchScreen in UIKit to Version statement in.xcodeproj?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I have a Label in LaunchScreen in UIKit which shows version of application.I want that Label to be updated automatically when i update app in Appstore.Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You cannot do anything in the launch screen that relies on code running, because it's just a launch screen. You can write a splash screen as part of your app and display anything you like.